# How to get terminal output data into a python program?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am using 2 raspberry pi's to send data via 433mhz rf transmitter and reciver, it works in command line

On the reciver I type sudo RFSniffer
And on the transmitter I type sudo sendcode (12345)

The reciver will display the received code in the terminal,

However I need a program that will act on the codes recived,

I can use the subprocess module to send codes from python on the transmitter when differant inputs are triggered but how can I use the recived codes in python?

Comment: The same way as you send them: using `subprocess` module. Remember that `communicate` lets you access both `stderr` and `stdout` of the subprocess.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a python program that accepts input on the command line.  The use a bash script to pipe (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30759/whats-a-good-example-of-piping-commands-together) the output from your receiver to the python program.